# Is this equation time-invariant and autonomous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, invariance

I just came to this note

```
For any LTI system the transfer function is W(s)=X(s)/F(s)
e.g for the system x' + 3x = f(t),
the transfer function is  W=1/3+s
```

but this system has a term f(t) dependent on t so it shouldn't be autonomous, right?

Comment: Yes, maybe that is easier to see if you write the vector field as $\dot{x}(t)=f(t)-3x(t)=F(x(t),t)$.

Comment: then it's not autonomous?? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)

Comment: I responded on your last question, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is time-invariant since the parameters (e.g. the number 3 that multiplies the x) do not depend on time. The variables (x,f) can depend on time.